# "In charge of" for "under the care of" in AmE

Tags: american-english

Checking on the validity of "to charge" as a correct fit for "to claim", "to assert" in some previous OP, I came across the expression "in charge of" pointed up by the Collins dictionary -- besides its shared meaning [having responsibility for] -- as an Americanism for "under the care of".

> http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+charge+of
>
> ***34. In charge of**: **a.** Having responsibility for -- **b.** US: under the care of*
>
> Collins English Dictionary, complete and unabridged, Ed. 2003

The funny thing to it is both meanings of "in charge of" obviously go in opposite directions, to such an extent that -- with an unclear or unspecified context  -- saying "The old lady was in charge of her grandchildren" could mean that the old lady had responsibility for her grandchildren (for instance, because both parents
are dead), but also just about the contrary, i.e the old lady was under the care of her grandchilden (both parents are dead and the old lady [their gramdmother] suffers from severe Alzheimer's).

Which of those meanings of "in charge of" is actually more common to modern day AmE?

E.g.

> Parents can safely leave their children in charge of the babysitter. [source](http://www.cheyennebottoms.net/an-outdoor-security-camera-adds-safety-to-the-home)

Comment: Apparently [Thomas Hardy](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=N1EbAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT2897&lpg=PT2897&dq=%22children+in+charge+of+a+nurse%22&source=bl&ots=UeOoKdeC5b&sig=mwfBnR8lC3zeo_k5-UhbX57oMkA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FFwzU6nUAcXY7AamroCIAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22children%20in%20charge%20of%20a%20nurse%22&f=false) used the expression in the same way, but it's very unusual (and ambiguous).

Comment: I can’t imagine why this is marked “American English”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OED notes this double-edge grammatical sword under sense 13b, which
notes that this phrase is used both actively and passively:

> **13 b.** ***in
>   charge (of***) is used both actively and passively; *e.g*.
>   to leave children *in charge of* a nurse, or a nurse *in
>   charge of* the children.  The latter is the more recent use;
>   thence ***officer, clerk, curate in charge***, i.e. having
>   actually the charge or care (of a place, business, etc.), ‘on duty’.

I wouldn’t expect to encounter the earlier, “reversed” direction in modern writing, at least not without an extra *the*:

- *leave children in* (or *under*)  ***the** charge of a nurse*

Answer (score 4):

While the children may try to take advantage, the parents would never leave them *in charge of* the babysitter. ([ref](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+charge)) They would leave them **in the charge of** the baby sitter. ([ref](http://www.yourdictionary.com/in-the-charge-of))

Answer (score 2):

I think the phrasing is slightly different.  Your reference makes a distinction between the two uses:

**in charge of**--having the care or supervision of: *She is in charge of two libraries.*

Also, **in the charge of** --under the care or supervision of: *The books are in **the** charge of the accounting office.*

While I would understand the intended meaning of the example you provide, it really should be *safely leave their children in **the** charge of the babysitter*. Furthermore, this use sounds outdated.  It would sound more natural to use ***with*** the babysitter or ***in the care of*** the babysitter.

Comment: You didn't check on the good reference, Mike. I said in the CD [Collins Dictionary]. Please check it back. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+charge+of http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+charge

Comment: @NourishedGourmet. Yes, I copied the quote from your reference.  If you scroll down to #49, option b.

Comment: Correct, but it explicitly days 49 b. also in the charge of. "Also" means that both "in charge of" and "in the charge of" can be used interchangeably to mean "under the case" -- in AmE at least -- as if you scroll further down, you'll see for yourself that this meaning to "under the care of" is clearly pointed up as "US" in Collins Dictionary.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet. You are correct, if one scrolls way down there is this statement referencing this for US.  My apologies!  I'm glad it is there, because in 40 years of speaking AmE, I am completely ignorant that this is used or considered correct.  My experience is limited, as I've only lived in four regions of the US.  Undoubtedly there is some pocket of the country that uses this form without prohibitive ambiguity.  I'll have to read 49.b. again, I understood a meaning reflecting my experience.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between "in charge of" and being "one of her charges"; they are not interchangeable. The one *in charge of* is the one who is responsible or in control.

> treasurer. noun. someone who is in charge of the money that belongs to an organization.

Note, the treasurer is in charge of the money; the money is not in charge of the treasurer.

In case you're curious about other American understandings of the word *charge*,  they are many, all common. The most common:

*Charge* it - put it on the credit card.
Smith and his team are *in charge of* this project - they are responsible for it.
Man *charged* with theft - a criminal complaint lodged against someone.
That (person or establishment) *charges* too much - amount demanded for fees/services.
My battery is dead. I need a *charge*. Energy.
The atmosphere was *charged* with emotion. Loaded.
*Charge!* - rush forward.
He was *charged* from behind. - assailed or football.
positive or negative *charge* - ion charge
*Charge* your weapon - load it; or the explosive is in place.